# input 2 variables separated by a comma in a single line

Tags: python

Is it possible to input 2 numbers `int` or `float` separated by a comma in a single line?

Say after the program runs it would ask the user to `Enter a range:` then the user would input `2,3`. So the variable range is `[2,3]`. As far as I know `range_choice.split()` is the only way.

Comment: Yup, split is the way to do it.

Comment: `split` isn't the _only_ way but it is the quickest and easiest. One thing you might have to keep in mind are bad cases like what would happen if the user didn't enter anything, enters only 1 value with/without a comma, etc.

Comment: Don't call the variable `input`, that's a built in function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
num1,num2 = map(float, raw_input('Enter a range: ').split(','))
```

Alternatively, if you want to allow commas in the second value, use [`partition`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.partition) instead of [`split`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.split):

```
s1,_,s2 = raw_input('Enter a range: ').partition(',')
```

In this case, you'll have to convert the two strings to numbers by yourself.

Comment: .split is better than this, it's not a better option.

Comment: @utdemir Updated with more details on when to use which.

Comment: You need to be able to sanitize the input so assigning the values right away will cause exceptions on bad input.

Comment: @Manny D Sorry, I don't follow. The first line throws exceptions when there are not exactly two values, or non-float values. It's quite pythonic to catch these `ValueError`s and handle malformed input.

Comment: @ phihag I followed what you suggested and it works fine. When I do it in the shell then its ok. It prints the range like (2.0, 3.0) if I type "num1,num2". But if I run it as a .py file then I have got the statement as " print num1,num2" then it just prints 2.0 3.0 without brackets and comma. Why is it so? How do I get them? Thanks

Comment: @cvani To convert back to a string, specify the precise string format. You're looking for `print(repr((num1, num2)))`, or, instead of relying on Python's semantics, `print ('(%s, %s)' % (num1, num2))`. The `print` statement has some legacy functionality you're running into. Put `from __future__ import print_function` at the top of your script to get the new Python 3 behavior of a print *function*.

Answer (score 0):

num1, num2 = raw_input('Enter a range: ').split(',')

Answer (score 0):

```
     x,y = input("Enter range: ")
```

If you want them as numbers it's best not to use raw_input.

Comment: No! Don't unconditionally evaluate arbitrary input. `input` is bad, and it's why `raw_input` has replace it as `input` on Python 2.

Comment: @Josh `input` is an unnecessary security hole (and therefore going away in Python 3) since you allow the user to execute arbitrary programs. Also, this doesn't guarantee `x` and `y` are numbers (for example, with the input `"ab"`)

Answer (score 0):

It's my understanding that [`ast.literal_eval`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) is safe:

```
>>> x, y = ast.literal_eval(raw_input('Enter a range: '))
Enter a range: 5, 6
>>> x, y
(5, 6)
```

Comment: Or [`input`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/functions.html#input) instead of `raw_input` for Python 3.

Answer (score 0):

In python3 you can directly use input() method instead of raw_input()

```
var1,var2 = input().split(',')
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can use:**

*for int*

```
a,b = map(int,input().split(','))
```

or

```
a,b = [int(i) for i in input().split(',')]
```

*for float*

```
a,b = map(float,input().split(','))
```

**Syntax:**

```
var1 sep var2 sep ... sep varn = map(type, input().split('sep'))
```

or

```
var1 sep var2 sep ... sep varn = [type(var) for var in input().split('sep')]
```

*for string*

```
a, b = input().split(',')
```